# Сериализовать Json с сохранением типов

Tags: java, json, gson

Есть контейнер:

```java
public class Container {
    private ArrayList<Person> arrayList;
    public Container()
    {
        arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    public Container(ArrayList<Person> arrayList)
    {
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
    }
    @Element(name = "PersonList")
    public List<Person> getArrayList() {
        return arrayList;
    }

    @Element(name = "PersonList")
    public void setArrayList(ArrayList<Person> arrayList) {
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
    }

    public boolean add(Person person)
    {
        return  arrayList.add(person);
    }

    public boolean remove(Person item)
    {
        return arrayList.remove(item);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Container{" +
                "arrayList=" + arrayList +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Его нужно сериализовать в, а затем десериализовать из Json.

```
public class MyJSON {
    public static String serialize(Object obj)
    {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        return gson.toJson(obj);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    public static boolean serializeToFile(Object obj, String path) {
        try (FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(path)) {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            gson.toJson(obj, fw);
            return true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static Object deserialize(String str, Class type)
    {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        return  gson.fromJson(str, type);
    }

    public static Object deserialize(String str, Type type )
    {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        return  gson.fromJson(str, type);
    }

}
```

От класса `Person` наследуются классы `Listener` и `Student`. Именно объекты этих классов и должен содержать контейнер, но возникает ошибка десериализации. Необходимо конкретно указывать, экземпляром какого класса является объект.

```java
Container cont = new Container();




        Listener pet = new Listener();
        pet.setName("Alex");
        pet.setsName("Goilo");
        pet.setOrg(Listener.organizations.BGTU);
        cont.add(pet);
        cont.add(pet);
        String str = MyJSON.serialize(cont.getArrayList());
        Log.d("Json", "onCreate: " + str);
        ArrayList<Person> arr2 = (ArrayList<Person>) MyJSON.deserialize(str,new TypeToken<ArrayList<Listener>>(){}.getType());
        Container cont2 = new Container(arr2);
        Log.d("Json", "onCreate: 2 " + cont2);
```

`new TypeToken<ArrayList<Listener>>(){}.getType()` Именно это мне не подходит. Нужно, чтобы работало с `TypeToken<ArrayList<Person>>(){}.getType()`. Нужна универсальная сериализация для всех классов унаследованных от `Person`. Как это реализовать?

Comment: Это возможно, но тут все зависит от процессора, который ты используешь. Для Jackson есть [отличный пример](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30386694/5506820)

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению, в таком случае нужно держать информацию о классе элемента списка, по крайней мере, прямо в JSON. Например, привычный JSON-массив

```
[
    {},
    {},
    {}
]
```

может стать:

```
[
    {"type":"foo.Foo","value":{}}
    {"type":"foo.Bar","value":{}}
    {"type":"foo.Baz","value":{}}
]
```

Допустим, есть следующая иерархия классов:

```java
abstract class Super {

    private final String name;

    private Super(final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    static final class Sub1
            extends Super {

        Sub1() {
            super("A1");
        }

    }

    static final class Sub2
            extends Super {

        Sub2() {
            super("B2");
        }

    }

}
```

А также некая обёртка, которая косвенно ссылается на базовый (в данном случае абстрактный класс):

```java
final class SuperWrapper {

    List<Super> supers;
    List<String> strings;

}
```

Тогда для преобразования списков в такие JSON-массивы и наоборот можно использовать:

```java
final class ListElementTypeAwareTypeAdapterFactory
        implements TypeAdapterFactory {

    // TypeToken обладает наибольшей гибкостью  
    private final Predicate<? super TypeToken<?>> strategy;

    private ListElementTypeAwareTypeAdapterFactory(final Predicate<? super TypeToken<?>> strategy) {
        this.strategy = strategy;
    }

    static TypeAdapterFactory getListElementTypeAwareTypeAdapterFactory(final Predicate<? super TypeToken<?>> strategy) {
        return new ListElementTypeAwareTypeAdapterFactory(strategy);
    }

    @Override
    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(final Gson gson, final TypeToken<T> typeToken) {
        // Смотрим, список ли это
        if ( List.class.isAssignableFrom(typeToken.getRawType()) ) {
            // Да? Пробуем определить как он параметризирован
            final Type elementType = getTypeParameter0(typeToken.getType());
            final TypeToken<?> elementTypeToken = TypeToken.get(elementType);
            // И спрашиваем в стратегии, можно ли обрабатывать такой класс
            if ( strategy.test(elementTypeToken) ) {
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                final TypeAdapter<T> typeAdapter = (TypeAdapter<T>) new ListElementTypeAwareTypeAdapter<>(gson);
                return typeAdapter;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static Type getTypeParameter0(final Type type) {
        if ( !(type instanceof ParameterizedType) ) {
            return Object.class;
        }
        final ParameterizedType parameterizedType = (ParameterizedType) type;
        return parameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }

    private static final class ListElementTypeAwareTypeAdapter<E>
            extends TypeAdapter<List<E>> {

        private static final String TYPE = "type";
        private static final String VALUE = "value";

        private final Gson gson;

        private ListElementTypeAwareTypeAdapter(final Gson gson) {
            this.gson = gson;
        }

        @Override
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        public void write(final JsonWriter out, final List<E> list)
                throws IOException {
            if ( list == null ) {
                out.nullValue();
            } else {
                writeJsonArray(out, list);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public List<E> read(final JsonReader in)
                throws IOException {
            return in.peek() == NULL
                    ? null
                    : readJsonArray(in);
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        private void writeJsonArray(final JsonWriter out, final Iterable<E> list)
                throws IOException {
            out.beginArray();
            for ( final E element : list ) {
                if ( element == null ) {
                    out.nullValue();
                } else {
                    out.beginObject();
                    out.name(TYPE);
                    out.value(element.getClass().getName());
                    out.name(VALUE);
                    gson.toJson(element, element.getClass(), out);
                    out.endObject();
                }
            }
            out.endArray();
        }

        private List<E> readJsonArray(final JsonReader in)
                throws IOException {
            try {
                final List<E> list = new ArrayList<>();
                in.beginArray();
                while ( in.hasNext() ) {
                    if ( in.peek() == NULL ) {
                        in.nextNull();
                        list.add(null);
                    } else {
                        in.beginObject();
                        requireNextName(TYPE, in);
                        final Type elementClass = Class.forName(in.nextString());
                        requireNextName(VALUE, in);
                        final E element = gson.fromJson(in, elementClass);
                        list.add(element);
                        in.endObject();
                    }
                }
                in.endArray();
                return list;
            } catch ( final ClassNotFoundException ex ) {
                throw new IOException(ex);
            }
        }

        private static void requireNextName(final String expectedName, final JsonReader in)
                throws IOException {
            final String actualName = in.nextName();
            if ( !expectedName.equals(actualName) ) {
                throw new MalformedJsonException("Expected " + expectedName + " but was " + actualName);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Пример использования:

```java
public static void main(final String... args) {
    final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapterFactory(getListElementTypeAwareTypeAdapterFactory(typeToken -> typeToken.getRawType() == Super.class))
            .create();
    System.out.println("--- BEFORE ---");
    final SuperWrapper before = new SuperWrapper();
    before.supers = asList(null, new Super.Sub1(), new Super.Sub2());
    before.strings = asList("foo", "bar", "baz");
    dumpSuperWrapper(before);
    System.out.println("--- JSON ---");
    final String wrapperJson = gson.toJson(before);
    System.out.println("\t" + wrapperJson);
    System.out.println("--- AFTER ---");
    dumpSuperWrapper(gson.fromJson(wrapperJson, SuperWrapper.class));
}

private static void dumpSuperWrapper(final SuperWrapper superWrapper) {
    System.out.println("\t" + superWrapper.strings);
    System.out.println("\t" + superWrapper.supers);
    System.out.println("\t" + superWrapper.supers.get(0));
    System.out.println("\t" + superWrapper.supers.get(1).getClass().getName());
    System.out.println("\t" + superWrapper.supers.get(2).getClass().getName());
}
```

> --- BEFORE ---
>     [foo, bar, baz]
>     [null, ru.q573095.Super$Sub1@484b61fc, ru.q573095.Super$Sub2@45fe3ee3]
>     null
>     ru.q573095.Super$Sub1
>     ru.q573095.Super$Sub2
>   --- JSON ---
>     {"supers":[null,{"type":"ru.q573095.Super$Sub1","value":{"name":"A1"}},{"type":"ru.q573095.Super$Sub2","value":{"name":"B2"}}],"strings":["foo","bar","baz"]}
>   --- AFTER ---
>     [foo, bar, baz]
>     [null, ru.q573095.Super$Sub1@4926097b, ru.q573095.Super$Sub2@762efe5d]
>     null
>     ru.q573095.Super$Sub1
>     ru.q573095.Super$Sub2

Обратите внимание, что тип элементов `SuperWrapper.supers` определяется корректно и после десериализации.